# Data socket timed out with apt-get, stretch, and ssh

Tags: ssh, apt, raspbian-stretch

Trying to utilize ssh with apt-get over ssh on a stretch RPi.  When doing so, however, I receive a data socket timeout error.  It works fine using jessie.  It might be a bug as similarly described by https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2284, https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196852, and https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/98, however, interested whether there might be a workaround.  My /etc/apt/sources.list includes deb ssh://michael@12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable.  Please see the following.  Any recommended solutions?  Thank you

```
michael@pi3:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Ign:3 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable InRelease
Ign:4 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable Release
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Ign:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Ign:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Ign:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Get:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages [420 B]
Ign:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Ign:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en
Ign:5 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient all Packages
Err:6 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient armhf Packages
Data socket timed out
Ign:7 ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable/comclient Translation-en_GB
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch ssh://12.345.67.890/home/comclient/repo/dists/stable/comclient/binary-armhf/Packages Data socket timed out
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
michael@pi3:~ $ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/michaelclient.list
michael@pi3:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
michael@pi3:~ $
```